# Как лучше парсить выдачу Яндекса?

Tags: парсер, синтаксический-анализ, яндекс-поиск

Через curl обращаюсь к странице выдачи, он меня кидает на страницу с каптчей. Через Antigate распознаю каптчу и шлю обратно Яндексу, а он меня опять на каптчу и так несколько раз.
Каптча распознается правильно. Запросы все идут с одно ip и user-agent.

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Посмотрите какие заголовки отправляет браузер, напр хром, и отправляйте курлом идентичные заголовки, думаю что это поможет.
Просто яндекс понимает что его парсят, так как нет каких-либо заголовков вот и кидает капчу

Ну и знайте лимит, не делайте over 100 запросов в секунду.

Comment: Зачем вообще такие сложности, если есть [API](http://api.yandex.ru/xml/)?

Comment: Yandex XML выдача, немного отличается. Нужны реальные результаты, в реальной выдаче.